Hall-Littlewood polynomials for $n$-tuples that are not partitions
For some calculations related to the unramified principal series of ${\rm GL}(n)$ over a $p$-adic field, I need to compute Hall-Littlewood polynomials that are associated to $n$-tuples that are not partitions. This question has already been asked in the following post :
Hall-Littlewood polynomials of non-dominant weights
with no complete answer.
Edit (after Per Alexandersson's remark). I am looking for a computer program or a formula that can be implemented on a computer.

What do you mean by 'compute'? Are you looking for a computer program, any formula, or a formula with specific properties?

@Per Alexandersson I edited my post.

I mean, the formula you linked can be implemented, probably not too difficult. (I can probably code it up in Mathematica fairly quickly, but it might not be very efficient. For what parameters say would you need to be able to compute it?) It might be that the case you are asking about is closely related to the larger family of Catalan symmetric functions: https://symmetricfunctions.com/kschur.htm#catalanSymmetric
Can it perhaps be the case that your polynomials are related to these in an easy fashion?

@PerAlexandersson Thanks for your comments. Of course I can use and implement the formula but I hoped that these polynomials were already known and implemented somewhere.
